# Collatz Sequence: Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Chapter 3 Practice Project

Tags: python

This is my working code:

```
number = int(input())
while number > 1:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = int(number) // 2
        print (number)
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        number = 3 * int(number) + 1
        print (number)
```

Now I'm trying to add the exception that if user input has non-integer value, it should print 'Enter a number'

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(raw_input())
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number!")
while number > 1:
    ....
```

EDIT: As noted in a comment by Anton, use `raw_input` in Python 2, and `input` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a complete beginner so I would appreciate all kinds of tips. Here is how I managed to solve the problem, and for now it seems to work fine:

```html
def collatz(number):
    
    if number%2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    else:
        return 3*number+1
        
print ('Enter a number:')

try:
    number = int(input())

    while True:            
            if collatz(number) != 1:
                number= collatz(number)
                print(number)
            else:
                print('Success!')
                break        
except ValueError:
    print('Type an integer, please.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `ValueError` for the `except`. From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError):

> *exception* `ValueError`
>   Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

```
try:
    number = int(input())
    while number > 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number = int(number) // 2
            print (number)
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            number = 3 * int(number) + 1
            print (number)
except ValueError:
    print('Enter a number')
```

Comment: With `input()`, you are more likely to get `SyntaxError` or `NameError` than `ValueError`...

Comment: It's for python 3. `Input` in python 3 is the same as `raw_input` in python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You could do this-

```
 while number != 1:
    try:
        if number % 2 == 0:
           number = int(number) // 2
           print (number)
        elif number % 2 == 1:
           number = 3 * int(number) + 1
           print (number)
     except ValueError:
        print('Enter a number')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    else:
        return 3 * number + 1

while True:
    try:
        value = int(input("Eneter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("enter a valid integer!")


while value != 1:
    print(collatz(value))
    value = collatz(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def coll(number):

    while number !=1:
        if number%2==0:
            number= number//2
            print(number)

        else:
            number= 3*number+1
            print(number)
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter the no:"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number")


print(coll(number))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
# My fuction (MINI-Program)
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    else:
        return 3 * number + 1
# try & except clause for errors for non integers from the users input
try:
    userInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    # Main loops till we get to the number 1
    while True:
        number = collatz(userInput)
        if number !=1:
            userInput = number
            print(userInput)
        else:
            print(1)
            break
except ValueError:
    print("Numbers only! Restart program")
```